# Deploy angular project on server in cpanel and show it on website subfolder

Tags: angular

I am trying to run my angular project on my site sub-folder
I did all the below steps to deploy my project to server.

1. Start with the production build:
   ng build --prod
2. Copy everything within the output folder (dist/ by default) to a folder on the server.
3. Configure the server to redirect requests for missing files to index.html.

When i inspect my page on my site here http://festiveloans.com/my-app/
I see below in HTML while inspect element.

Comment: What is defined base path in index.html of angular project?

Comment: <base href="/">